# Forcing vertical scrollbar re-calcuation in a hierarchical tree class derived from mx.controls.Tree

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I'm working (for my sins) on a Flex 3.3 project, which unfortunately cannot be upgraded to a newer SDK version at this stage, and have hit an issue with the custom hierarchical tree class (subclassing `mx.controls.Tree`) we're using. *Excuse the spelling; the previous developer had a fear of dictionaries...*

```
public class HierachyTree extends Tree

public function HierachyTree()
{
    super();
    iconFunction = itemIconFunc;
    // etc.
}
```

I'm using a solution somewhere between these [two](http://www.davidarno.org/2009/04/01/how-to-filter-all-nodes-of-a-flex-tree-component/) [methods](http://richardleggett.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/05/11/filtering-hierachical-data-in-flex-itree) (basically, implementing `ITreeDataDescriptor`) in order to add live text filtering to the component, and it's working so far:

```
public class HierachyTreeFilteredDataDescriptor implements ITreeDataDescriptor
{
    private var filter:Function

    public function HierachyTreeFilteredDataDescriptor(filterFunction:Function)
    {
        this.filter = filterFunction;
    }

    public function getChildren(node:Object, model:Object=null):ICollectionView
    {
        var children:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([]);
        // Filter the children...
        return children;
    }

    public function hasChildren(node:Object, model:Object=null):Boolean
    {
        var treeItem:Object = node as Object;

        if (! (treeItem is ScenarioMeta)) return (treeItem as Object).children.length > 0;
        else return false;
    }
```

The issue is that (with `tree:HierachyTree`) neither `tree.maxVerticalScrollPosition` nor the protected property `tree.verticalScrollBar.maxScrollPosition` updates when the search string is changed.

I've tried calling `invalidateList()` and `invalidateDisplayList()` on `tree` — and calling `invalidateDisplayList()` and `invalidateSize()` on `tree.verticalScrollBar` — to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let me get this straight, what you're trying to accomplish is filter the data as per a search string inserted which should then refresh the tree?

If that's the case, it's fairly simple as long as you're using ArrayCollection as the data provider for the tree:

```
// Check if data is ArrayCollection
var ac:ArrayCollection;
if(tree.dataProvider is ArrayCollection)
{
   ac = ArrayCollection(tree.dataProvider);
}
else if(tree.dataProvider is HierarchicalData) // Check if it's hierarchical data
{
   ac = HierarchicalData(tree.dataProvider).source as ArrayCollection;
}

// filter - specify custom filter function somewhere, look at docs on how to implement
ac.filterFunction = someFilterFunction; 
ac.refresh(); // Does the filtering and lets the tree know that it should redraw all nodes
```

I think you get the idea.  Much easier to do this based on the data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but both articles I linked to specifically recommended against using `filterFunction` on `ArrayCollection` — they explain that applying a filterFunction doesn't automatically recurse, and manually recursing causes problems down the line.

Comment: Ahhh, there was no mention of child objects in your question.  You're right, the filter function only goes one layer in (because ArrayCollection assumes flat data).  However, you're going into a more complex area, and that is creating a new data structure.  You're probably want to create a new class that extends HierarchicalData and has a filterFunction and refresh functions within that.  From here, you'll need to recurse through all children to filter out what's what and save it to a new array so that you have both original and filtered array.  I think this is only proper way of doing it.

Comment: I readily admit that Flex isn't really a strength of mine, but I can't see how reimplementing a data structure is going to solve a visual bug: the filtering is already working, but the vertical scrollbars don't update (and it's thus possible to scroll to non-existent, blank white, areas of `tree`). Thanks again for your answers

Comment: You're not 'reimplementing' anything, you're adding a feature that isn't there yet.  What you're doing is changing the view and not the data, which is one way of doing it, but then you hit problems like these.  It's much easier to change a data structure than it is to change a view.  What happens if you're to change to a new Spark Tree (which isn't out yet), you then have you change all of your view code to reflect it.  If you use the data structure, you just plop it in.  Same goes if you ant to change the filter from somewhere else within your application.  Your code is more flexible in data.

Comment: I had no luck trying to change the data set as described, and ended up using a manual "filter" button in conjunction with implementing `ITreeDataDescriptor` instead. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have completely the same situation. I have a need to filter the whole tree, and I did use the solution from those 2 blogs.
Tried to *validateList()*, *validateDisplayList()*, tried to return a new collection(not filtered) on getChildren in data descriptor, but that caused other issues.
The following was the easiest and worked for me the best:

> treeDataProvider.dispatchEvent(new
>   CollectionEvent(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, false, false,
>   CollectionEventKind.RESET));

Comment: Partly as a result of not having been able to solve this problem (and partly because a "Filter" button actually worked a little better for the particular application), I abandoned this approach. Thanks for your answer, though: I'll dig out my original code and try your suggestion so I can "accept".